# Google Analytics shows 0 users

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

How could I investigate further what might be going on here?

I have an Adwords campaign running, and I have around 10 clicks per day.

My website has GTM code, and GA is therefore managed in the GTM.

However, Google Analytics shows 0 users vs. 7 days.

[image]

Is that because Google Analytics doesn't show me the number of users today, so it's 0, or have I misconfigured something?

Today I got 3 clicks already, but that isn't shown here, I think.

When I switch to "Last 28 days", I get a different picture:
[image]

Am I doing something wrong here, or am I just looking at it the wrong way?

Comment: are you using GA free? if yes, then it takes 24-72 hrs to get the data reflected in GA.

Comment: Is there anything you have changed on the 13th or 14th July, where the chart seems to drop to zero? (E.g. GTM settings, Analytics filters) That could be a starting point for your investigation. Also, you should check, if you see any traffic in Analytics realtime view, when you visit the site yourself, assuming you make a test, that is not filtered.

Comment: Yes, the fact that it takes 24-72 hours to get reflected seems to have been the problem here. I changed something in GTM, obviously that made everything drop for some time. Now, several days later, it's all back to normal again.